# render plot doesn't appear

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am using the code below to render a plot but the plot doesn't appear.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "George"
date: "12/3/2018"
output:
    flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
runtime: shiny
---

    ```{r global, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(flexdashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(GGally)


x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(11,22,33)
z <- data.frame(x, y)
```

Introduction
=======================================================================

### General info

- A

- B



Corr
=======================================================================

### Correlation
```{r include=TRUE, results='hide'}
renderPlot({
    GGally::ggpairs(z)
})

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd remove what you have in the chunk options:

````
```{r}

renderPlot({
    GGally::ggpairs(z)
})

```
````